# Server parse error can't find masterpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im creating a website using visual studio and everything worked well when i debugged it yesterday. But now when i try to load it i get a parse error and it can't find my masterpage. The error i get is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PToi2.png)

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: try to replace `CodeBehind` by `CodeFile` and don't waste your working hours on facebook. _YourBoss :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DeliveryDatabase.master.cs" Inherits="DeliveryDatabase.DeliveryDatabase" %>
```